# How to achieve multiple row criteria in single table

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> select * from productdetails;
+----------+---------+--------+
| customer | product | is_use |
+----------+---------+--------+
|        1 |       1 |      0 |
|        1 |       2 |      0 |
|        1 |       3 |      1 |
|        2 |       1 |      1 |
|        2 |       2 |      0 |
|        2 |       3 |      1 |
|        3 |       1 |      1 |
|        3 |       2 |      1 |
|        3 |       3 |      1 |
|        4 |       1 |      0 |
|        4 |       2 |      1 |
|        4 |       3 |      1 |
+----------+---------+--------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How to get the customers for using both product 1 and 2 from the above table

Comment: You should have added the expected result, which is customer 3 only as far as I understand, because that is the only customer using (is_use = 1) both products 1 and 2.

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to know which customers use both products, you'd aggreagte per customer:

```
select customer 
from productdetails
group by customer
having sum(product = 1 and is_use = 1) > 0
   and sum(product = 2 and is_use = 1) > 0
;
```

Comment: It was working fine, but  It may cause any performance issue, because the table have 10cr rows

Comment: indexing would help @Aaryan `productdetails.(customer, product, is_use)` or a covering index `productdetails.(customer, product, is_use, customer)`

Comment: You can add a where clause to speed this up: `where product in (1,2) and is_use = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions using `IN(1,2)` will find customers who use *either* product 1 or product 2 (or both).

If you want to find customers who use *both* product 1 and product 2, you need to test for both simultaneously.

But a WHERE clause naturally applies conditions in the context of only one row at a time.

So you need to get two rows onto one row somehow.

The best way to do this is with a self-join:

```
SELECT p1.customer
FROM product_detail AS p1
JOIN product_detail AS p2 ON p1.customer = p2.customer 
WHERE p1.product = 1 AND p1.is_use = 1
  AND p2.product = 2 AND p2.is_use = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use IN clause:

```
SELECT customer
FROM   product_detail
WHERE  product IN (1, 2)
AND    is_use = 1;
```

Comment: using "is_use = 1 "  column also